# How should I request that a TLD implement DNSSEC?

Tags: dnssec, tld

I want to put pressure on the .social TLD so they can implement DNSSec, however the company I purchased the domain name is simply a reseller (NameCheap).

I don't think that opening a ticket with them is as effective as contacting the TLD owner itself.

How should I identity and ask a given TLD Owner to implement DNSSec?

The steps I tried include

- Checking with Internic, and see who the registrars are
- It is difficult to open a ticket if you don't already own a domain from those resellers

What is the best way to proceed?

Comment: http://rightside.co/ and they already implement DNSSEC on social.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TLD is signed, maybe move registrars?

Only these TLDs are supported by Namecheap, however you could always try to [add DS records yourself.](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9722/2232/managing-dnssec-for-domains-pointed-to-custom-dns) but only if your zone is using Custom NS.

Currently Supported TLDs: .com
.net
.info
.io
.bid
.cloud
.college
.design
.feedback
.security
.top
.trade
.webcam
.xyz

Source [CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/209833347-How-to-add-a-DS-record-to-Namecheap)

```
dig +dnssec DS social.

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4 <<>> +dnssec DS social.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48868
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 1280
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;social.                                IN      DS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
social.                 84594   IN      DS      32212 8 1 BA0088DADB38E5F205ECA4C71DCCF976C2DACFAB
social.                 84594   IN      DS      32212 8 2 1FF8492BF0DDFE3C035C6E21CF7F53110B414F23F06DF3D06C87C67A B5D3385F
social.                 84594   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20161220170000 20161207160000 39291 . gozLeU8NuQukhYHBTlvMAXT8pAX+gVl2aR2QEDP9rOcBm9f/L3d7Wrz9 BSYrGZ22TmySMzucdHrud4Q18/6cn5t17yGvK/RmYTRVlF/lzW+ZgwJW R3nNu0W4DdDn6+ufd35aO2GW5OEodPqhRD87bilW1eScTUePtp53tI2f QphIOcOc4f/C3F5kkOo5ZAPlxcfqnur4LmzW8Y6EBKqk+O7c3g2n5BaG hEuFZi+G2ioZTs2QT5go3X0dTExPWhi12PSvSMvM+6CZ6J2Psy265n16 byhiLcddwQef6kcCOjUi3OQn37Zk90wu3+OJnSFtXih+WwyA3OOt3JDL JLHNuQ==

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.11.1#53(192.168.11.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec 07 18:03:24 Eastern Standard Time 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 406
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed command .. that helps. Do I need to move registrars, or is just the NS record enough

Comment: Name cheap has great customer service I'd give them a chance before leaving them. Also great products. I am just a consumer of there products not affiliated in any other way.

Comment: Google domains is cheaper and better but....also no dnssec support!